# Can't write to Firebase after changing rules

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Using the default rules for writing to my real-time database:

```
{
"rules": {
".read": "true",
".write": "true"
}
}
```

I am able to successfully save data to the database:

[image]

The code from my Android app looked like this:

```
  DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;
  mDatabaseReference = DatabaseReference.getInstance().getReference();
  ...
  mDatabaseReference.child("user").child(user.getUid()).setValue(user);
```

But to allow signed in users (email and password auth) to access only their own data, I found this [Firebase - How to write/read data per user after authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35822249/firebase-how-to-write-read-data-per-user-after-authentication). The answer uses a class `Firebase` that I can't seem to find anywhere. So I changed the rules to this:

```
{
  "rules": {
  "users": {
  "$uid": {
    ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
    ".read": "$uid === auth.uid"
  }
}
}
}
```

with a little modification to my java code:

```
    DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference, databaseReference;
    ...
    mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    databaseReference = mDatabaseReference.child("user");

    ...
    databaseReference.setValue(user); //user is a POJO
```

After deleting the old entries in my database and re-running my app, nothing happens when I try to save a new user.What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your rules, change `users` to `user`.

The name of the child in your Firebase rules

[image]

must match the name of the child in your java code.

[image]

Images added for clarity

Comment: Sloppy mistake :p

Comment: Very sloppy I've been on this for almost 6 hours :)

Comment: @ojonugwaochalifu sometimes it happens . I know .